# 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get image from web service and I'm getting an error.
**'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'**
My Code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;



namespace SmartPoster
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            // call web service here
            SmartPosterV1 a = new SmartPosterV1();

            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(a.returnTestImage());
            this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);                

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) is a WinForms control, and it's Image property is a  [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx).

In ASP.Net, you need to have a [System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx) in your web form and assign the ImageUrl property the URL of the image to be displayed.

Comment: changed using System.Web.UI.WebControls; to using System.Drawing; and it works fine.